# Error building Dockerfile for arm32v7 architecture with azure-storage-blob package

Tags: python, azure, dockerfile

When attempting to build a Dockerfile targeting the arm32v7 architecture, a peculiar error related to gcc arises. Specifically, the error message "unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory" emerges during the inclusion of the azure-storage-blob package version 12.6.0 in the requirements file. Surprisingly, excluding this package resolves the issue, enabling the Dockerfile to proceed without hindrance. Notably, other specified packages such as azure-iot-device, pytz, sympy, and python-dateutil remain unaffected by this adjustment.

Here are the package versions specified in the requirements file:

```
azure-storage-blob: 12.6.0
azure-iot-device: ~=2.7.0
pytz: 2023.3.post1
sympy: 1.10.1
python-dateutil: 2.8.2
```

Below is the Dockerfile (Dockerfile.arm32v7) snippet where the error occurs:

### Use the official Python image for ARM32v7 as the base image

```
FROM arm32v7/python:3.7-slim-buster
```

### Set the working directory in the container

```
WORKDIR /app
```

### Copy the Python application code and requirements.txt into the container

```
COPY requirements.txt /app/
COPY . .
```

### Run

```
pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
```

### Command to run the application

```
CMD [ "python3", "-u", "./main.py" ]
```

The full exception encountered during the build process is as follows:

[Exception Output]

This issue seems specific to the arm32v7 architecture and occurs during the installation of the azure-storage-blob package. Any insights or solutions to smoothly build the Dockerfile in the arm32v7 architecture would be greatly appreciated.